# LESS | Target elements without specific parent class

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have a HTML structure as shown below

```
<ul class="list list--sm">
    <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
        List item 1
          <ul>
              <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
                  List item 1.1
                    <ul>
                      <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
                           List item 1.1.1
                      </li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here I want to target the elements with class `list__item--draggable` that do not have a parent/grandparent with the class `list__item--draggable` i.e. the element with the text "List item 1". I want to achieve this using LESS. I do not want to use the > selector because it can be a nested structure with few more divs and other elements.

I am not able to think of a solution for this. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Your HTML seems incorrect. `<li>` elements cannot be nested directly in one another.

Comment: It's indeed a nested draggable list. I have changed div to ul tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible even in pure CSS:

```css
.list__item--draggable:not(.list__item--draggable *) {}
```

Try it:

```css
.list__item--draggable {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.list__item--draggable:not(.list__item--draggable *) {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list list--sm">
  <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
    List item 1
    <ul>
      <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
        List item 1.1
        <ul>
          <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
            List item 1.1.1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy, I now understand the concept.

Comment: This selects everything within the first .list__item__draggable - so if you for example try to highlight the List item 1 text, all the texts will be highlighted.

Comment: Correct, but the question is about *targeting*, not *applying styles* to that target.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on exactly how you want to style/restyle the children but here's a simple CSS example which highlights just that first text:

```css
.list__item--draggable {
  background: yellow;
}

ul ul,
ul ul .list__item--draggable {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list list--sm">
  <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
    List item 1
    <ul>
      <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
        List item 1.1
        <ul>
          <li class="list__item list__item--draggable">
            List item 1.1.1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, we change every occurence, then we change back those that are children.